# Retrieving public dns of EC2 instance with BOTO3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dns, boto3, amazon-ec2

I'm using ipython to get an understanding of Boto3 and interacting with EC2 instances. Here is the code I'm using to create an instance:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
client = boto3.client('ec2')


new_instance = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-d05e75b8',
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    InstanceType='t2.micro',
    KeyName=<name_of_my_key>,
    SecurityGroups=['<security_group_name>'],
    DryRun = False
    )
```

This starts an EC2 instance fine, and I can get the public DNS name, ip and other info from the AWS console. But, when I try to get the public DNS using Boto, by doing this:

```
new_instance[0].public_dns_name
```

Returns blank quotes. Yet, other instance details, such as:

```
new_instance[0].instance_type
```

Returns the correct information.

Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT:

So if I do:

```
def get_name(inst):
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    response = client.describe_instances(InstanceIds = [inst[0].instance_id])
    foo = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['NetworkInterfaces'][0]['Association']['PublicDnsName']
    return foo


foo = get_name(new_instance)
print foo
```

Then it will return the public DNS. But it doesn't make sense to me why I need to do all of this.

Answer (score 32):

The `Instance` object you get back is only hydrated with the response attributes from the `create_instances` call. Since the DNS name is not available until the instance has reached the running state [[1]](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.public_dns_name), it will not be immediately present. I imagine the time between you creating the instance and calling describe instances is long enough for the micro instance to start.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-f0091d91',
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    InstanceType='t2.micro',
    KeyName='<KEY-NAME>',
    SecurityGroups=['<GROUP-NAME>'])
instance = instances[0]

# Wait for the instance to enter the running state
instance.wait_until_running()

# Reload the instance attributes
instance.load()
print(instance.public_dns_name)
```

Comment: I tried instance.load, it gave me the error: "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'load'

Comment: For anyone else that has Alex's problem, the instance should be of type `ec2.Instance`, so check your logic. Also, reminder that the return value of `create_instances()` is a _list_ of `ec2.Instance` objects.

Comment: thanks - I was not sure why my instance (even after the wait call) still shows as pending, i wasn't using the load function.

Answer (score 3):

Here my wrapper:

```
import boto3
from boto3.session import Session

def credentials():
    """Credentials:"""
    session = Session(aws_access_key_id= 'XXXXXXXXX',
                      aws_secret_access_key= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-2')
    return ec2

def get_public_dns(instance_id):
    """having the instance_id, gives you the public DNS"""
    ec2 = credentials()
    instance = ec2.Instance(instance_id)
    instancePublicDNS = instance.public_dns_name
    return instancePublicDNS
```

Then you just need to use your instance_id to get public dns of any of your actives ec2:

```
dns = get_public_dns(instance_id)
```

Remember to change "region_name" to your zone and add your "aws_access_key_id" and "aws_secret_access_key"

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='aws_dev')
dev_ec2_client = session.client('ec2')
response = dev_ec2_client.describe_instances()
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['InstanceId', 'InstanceType', 'PrivateIpAddress','PublicDnsName'])
i = 0
for res in response['Reservations']:
    df.loc[i, 'InstanceId'] = res['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
    df.loc[i, 'InstanceType'] = res['Instances'][0]['InstanceType']
    df.loc[i, 'PrivateIpAddress'] = res['Instances'][0]['PrivateIpAddress']
    df.loc[i, 'PublicDnsName'] = res['Instances'][0]['PublicDnsName']
    i += 1
print df
```

Note:

1. Change this profile with your AWS profile name `profile_name='aws_dev'`
2. This code is working for Python3

Comment: The use of pandas seems to be overkill here.

Comment: @jarmod : I would like to see the values more into tabular presentation so we can prepare the inventory as well,  As we get the data from boto3, dicts are very complex in visualizing. And its a kind of template where we get the other aws attributes as well.

Comment: Appreciated the use of pandas because it made understanding the API interface easier