# How to retrieve Public DNS from a created AWS instance by a BOTO3 program?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Have the same problem as in [Retrieving public dns of EC2 instance with BOTO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34728477/retrieving-public-dns-of-ec2-instance-with-boto3/34751516)

First I create and run an instance:

```
r = client.run_instances(
ImageId=aws_config['base_ami'], 
MinCount=1, 
MaxCount=1,
KeyName=aws_config['key_name'],
InstanceType="t2.small",
NetworkInterfaces=[
{
    'DeviceIndex': 0,
    'SubnetId' : aws_config['subnet'],
    'Groups': aws_config['security_groups'],
    'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True            
}]                     
)
instance = r["Instances"][0]
```

The answer suggests using instance.load() to upload to the instance the new public DNS IP.  By the way, I can see the public IP from the AWS console

In my program I have the AttributeError after instance.load()

```
instance.load()
```

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'load

Comment: This is working as expected for me using the example you cited.  Boto3 version 1.6.7

Comment: @kenlukas you are right, I need to edit the post.  I used client.run_instances, it does not return a lit of instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that client.run_instances does not return the list of EC2 instances, it returns the list of instance dictionaries.

To convert return to the EC2 instance I did the following after the above code:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
inst = ec2.Instance(instance['InstanceId'])
```

Then inst.load() works and uploads the public DNS IP